# Google Map Autocomplete API not adding address options

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform on a website built with asp.net to autofill an address field. The problem is when I start typing, nothing happens. I'll go into dev tools, theres an element added by the API with a class `pac-container`. I'll set its display to block and see that it displays a small white dropdown with "Powered by Google" in the corner. I see in the working example that there are a list of divs with a class `pac-item` that are inside the `pac-container` and contain the suggested addresses when you begin typing an address. Does anyone know why I am not getting this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the source of your problem, but I found a [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/auto-complete-address-using-google-api-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/) here using asp.net in Google Maps Autocomplete API. you can check this one and use this as your guidelines. Also for more information about this, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#introduction).

Answer (score 4):

Let's call it a bug(at least it's not documented):

New  implementations(as of June 22) of the Javascript-API [require a key](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) and as it seems additionally also a actived **Places API Webservice** when you want to use the places-library(that's new and currently undocumented)

So: [activate the Places API Webservice in the developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend/overview) and wait 1-2 minutes

**Update:** it's still not documented, but at least confirmed -> https://plus.google.com/102023534640640210950/posts/4mtLcUFoyTv

Comment: This saved my life (and time). Indeed, in the developer console, in addition to Google Maps API, you need to activate the Places API, and then the autocomplete works. There is no error/warning raised, it's completely hidden...

Comment: My God I was debugging this for like an hour and had no idea why my previous solution that had worked wasn't working until I found this. They really need to send out emails or at least update their docs.